# MySQL - Order By column values, group according other column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
Name    1-3    4-6   7-9
------------------------
Dan       0      3     4
Jane      1      6     0
Mike      3      3     3
Dan       2      2     0
Jane      3      4     2
Dan       1      3     0
```

Here's order that needed to be done.

```
Name    1-3    4-6   7-9
------------------------
Dan       0      3     4
Dan       1      3     0
Dan       2      2     0
Mike      3      3     3
Jane      3      4     2
Jane      2      2     0
```

In short, the order by start with the highest number in field `7-9` have then group by the name, then order by again in each group name (in this ex. is `Dan` & `Jane`) according field `4-6` and `1-3`

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Name, `1-3`, `4-6`, `7-9`
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY `7-9` DESC, Name, `4-6` DESC, `1-3` DESC
```

Comment: i think the example is coincidence..
It should be order by `7-9` first

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo in your desired result, and try this:

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
join (
  select Name, max(`7-9`) orderby
  from yourtable
  group by Name
  order by max(`7-9`)
) t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name
order by orderby desc, `4-6` desc, `1-3`
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6acff/6)